# excluding relative paths in duplicity

Tags: duplicity

The [duplicity documentation](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/vers8/duplicity.1.html) doesn't appear to fully document its behaviour when relative paths (or bare filenames) are passed to the `--exclude` option.  If I pass the option `--exclude foo`, for example, will this cause each file or directory named `foo` in the entire heirarchy under `source_directory` to be excluded, or will it only exclude a file or directory with that name in `source_directory` itself?  If the latter is the case, is there a way to exclude `source_directory/foo` without having to type the full path to `source_directory` for each such option (other than by using a shell variable)?

Comment: For a src dir of `a/b/c` you could use `--exclude */*/*/foo` where the number of `*/` matches the src, but it is probably simpler as you say to use a variable. Note if you try `--exclude foo` with the above src you'll get an error `FilePrefixError` as the pattern foo is tested against the src.

Answer (score 0):

been a while since i looked at duplicity in/exclusion. but generally [duplicity 0.8 man page, section File Selection](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/vers8/duplicity.1.html#sect9) describes it pretty well.

duplicity only in/excludes during backup currently . all in/exclusions need to be absolute paths or contain wildcards as descibed in the man page. if you define a relative path duplicity will show an error like

```
Fatal Error: The file specification
    foo
cannot match any files in the base directory
    /home/user/
```

you asked

> If I pass the option --exclude foo, for example, will this cause each file or directory named foo in the entire heirarchy under source_directory to be excluded, or will it only exclude a file or directory with that name in source_directory itself?

neither nor. it will err out as shown above. if you want to exclude e.g. `/home/user/foo` when backing up `/home/user/` you will need to exclude it absolutely `--exclude /home/user/foo` . if you want all `foo` folders/files excluded you may use `--exclude '**/foo'` where '**' stands for any path.

> If the latter is the case, is there a way to exclude source_directory/foo without having to type the full path to source_directory for each such option (other than by using a shell variable)?

No, unfortunately you will need to give it (plain or as env var), redundant as it may seem. if you have lot's of exclusions consider using `--exclude-filelist` which my contain in/exclusions albeit it's naming.
Also there is `--exclude-if-present` which allows you to give a file name that indicates that a folder is to be excluded if it contains a file named thus.

hope that helps ..ede/duply.net

Comment: The documentation includes an example where a relative path is used: in the section toward the end covering the filelist options, the lines `dir/foo` and `+ dir/bar` are used.  The manual explains that *--include-filelist list.txt would be exactly the same as specifying --include dir/foo --include dir/bar --exclude ** on the command line.*